# Unable to get information on a Reducer using Redux

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, dispatch

I have a question with a Reducer, the problem is that I'm used to get data from an API which brings just Key Value Pairs something like:

```
       {
        "-MObNVR5e180MfhvtbRY": {
            "altura": "179 cm",
            "apellido": "Cuéllar De León",
            "edad": 31,
            "fecha_nacimiento": "20/10/1989",
            "imagen": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/alianzafc2021.appspot.com/o/yimmi%20cuellar.jpg?alt=media&token=144fa106-eabb-40c8-83b6-2e4b45034eda",
            "iso_code": "SV",
            "lugar_nacimiento": "San Julián",
            "nacionalidad": "El Salvador",
            "nombre_completo": "Yimmy Rodrigo Cuéllar De León",
            "nombre_corto": "Yimmy Cuéllar",
            "nombres": "Yimmy Rodrigo",
            "numero": 1,
            "pais": "El Salvador",
            "peso": "66 kg",
            "player_id": 108911,
            "posicion": "Portero"
        },
    }
```

Now I need to get the data from an API that has Arrays within the Array like this:

```
{
    "api": {
        "results": 13,
        "players": [
            {
                "player_id": 79308,
                "player_name": "Felipe Ponce Ramírez",
                "firstname": "Felipe",
                "lastname": "Ponce Ramírez",
                "number": null,
                "position": "Midfielder",
                "age": 32,
                "birth_date": "29/03/1988",
                "birth_place": "Ciudad Lerdo",
                "birth_country": "Mexico",
                "nationality": "Mexico",
                "height": "177 cm",
                "weight": "67 kg",
                "injured": null,
                "rating": null,
                "team_id": 4299,
                "team_name": "Alianza",
                "league_id": 2979,
                "league": "Primera Division",
                "season": "2020-2021",
                "captain": 0,
                "shots": {
                    "total": 0,
                    "on": 0
                },
                "goals": {
                    "total": 4,
                    "conceded": 0,
                    "assists": 0,
                    "saves": 0
                },
                "passes": {
                    "total": 0,
                    "key": 0,
                    "accuracy": 0
                },
                "tackles": {
                    "total": 0,
                    "blocks": 0,
                    "interceptions": 0
                },
                "duels": {
                    "total": 0,
                    "won": 0
                },
                "dribbles": {
                    "attempts": 0,
                    "success": 0
                },
                "fouls": {
                    "drawn": 0,
                    "committed": 0
                },
                "cards": {
                    "yellow": 2,
                    "yellowred": 0,
                    "red": 0
                },
                "penalty": {
                    "won": 0,
                    "commited": 0,
                    "success": 0,
                    "missed": 0,
                    "saved": 0
                },
                "games": {
                    "appearences": 6,
                    "minutes_played": 194,
                    "lineups": 2
                },
                "substitutes": {
                    "in": 4,
                    "out": 2,
                    "bench": 0
                }
            },
}
```

Someone told me that I will need to create a Data Model for each SubArray so I did and I used it in my Action File like this:

```
export const fetchEstadistica = player_id => {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        //any async code here!!!
        try {
            const response = await fetch(
                `https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v2/players/player/${player_id}.json`,
                {
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: new Headers({
                        'x-rapidapi-key': //Here Goes My API Key which I keep for Security Reasons,
                        'x-rapidapi-host': 'api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com',
                        'useQueryString': 'true'
                    })
                }
            );

            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error('Algo salio Mal!');
            }

            const resData = await response.json();
            const loadesApiResult = [];

            console.log(resData);

            //Arrays de la Estadistica del Jugador
            const loadedEstadistica = [];
            const loadedCards = [];
            const loadedGoals = [];
            const loadedGames = [];

            for (const key in resData) {
                loadesApiResult.push(
                    new ResultadoEstadistica(
                        key,
                        resData[key].results,
                        resData[key].players
                    )
                );
            }

            const apiData = loadesApiResult.players;

            for (const key in apiData){
                loadedEstadistica.push(
                    new PlayerEstadistica (
                        apiData[key].player_id,
                        apiData[key].player_name,
                        apiData[key].firstname,
                        apiData[key].lastname,
                        apiData[key].number,
                        apiData[key].position,
                        apiData[key].age,
                        apiData[key].birth_date,
                        apiData[key].birth_place,
                        apiData[key].birth_country,
                        apiData[key].nationality,
                        apiData[key].height,
                        apiData[key].weight,
                        apiData[key].injured,
                        apiData[key].rating,
                        apiData[key].team_id,
                        apiData[key].team_name,
                        apiData[key].league_id,
                        apiData[key].league,
                        apiData[key].season,
                        apiData[key].captain,
                        apiData[key].shots,
                        apiData[key].goals,
                        apiData[key].passes,
                        apiData[key].duels,
                        apiData[key].dribbles,
                        apiData[key].fouls,
                        apiData[key].cards,
                        apiData[key].penalty,
                        apiData[key].games,
                        apiData[key].substitutes,
                    )
                );
            }

            const playerDataGames = loadedEstadistica.games;
            
            for (const key in playerDataGames){
                loadedGames.push(
                    new Games(
                        playerDataGames[key].apperences,
                        playerDataGames[key].minutes_played,
                        playerDataGames[key].lineups
                    )
                );
            };

            const playerDataGoals = loadedEstadistica.goals;

            for (const key in playerDataGoals){
                loadedGoals.push(
                    new Goals(
                        playerDataGoals[key].total,
                        playerDataGoals[key].conceded,
                        playerDataGoals[key].assists,
                        playerDataGoals[key].saves
                    )
                );
            };

            const playerDataCards = loadedEstadistica.cards;

            for (const key in playerDataCards){
                loadedCards.push(
                    new Cards(
                        playerDataCards[key].yellow,
                        playerDataCards[key].yellowred,
                        playerDataCards[key].red
                    )
                );
            };

            dispatch({ type: SET_ESTADISTICA, estadistica: loadedEstadistica, goles: loadedGoals, juegos: loadedGames, tarjetas: loadedCards });
        } catch (err) {
            throw err;
        }
    };
};
```

Then I get this into my Readucer with the Type:

```
import { SET_JUGADORES, SET_ESTADISTICA } from "../actions/jugadores";

const initialState = {
    availablePlayers: [],
    estadistica: [],
    playerGoals: [],
    playerCards: [],
    playerGames: [],
}

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_JUGADORES:
            return {
                availablePlayers: action.players,
            };
        case SET_ESTADISTICA:
            return{
                estadistica: estadistica,
                // playerGoals: action.goles,
                // playerCards: action.tarjetas,
                // playerGames: action.juegos
            };
    }
    return state;
};
```

Finally, I go and call the Reducer from:

```
import React, {useState, useCallback, useEffect} from 'react';
import { ScrollView, Text, Image, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

const ProductDetailScreen = props => {
    const playerId = props.route.params.id;
    const estadId = props.route.params.statId;

    const selectedPlayer = useSelector(state => state.jugadores.availablePlayers.find(prod => prod.id === playerId));


    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [isRefreshing, setIsRefreshing] = useState(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState();

    const goles = useSelector(state => state.jugadores.estadistica);

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const loadEstad = useCallback (async (estadId) => {
        setError(null);
        setIsRefreshing(true);
        try {
            await dispatch(userActions.fetchEstadistica(estadId));
        } catch (err){
            setError(err.message);
        }
        setIsRefreshing(false);
    }, [dispatch, setIsLoading, setError]);

    useEffect(() => {       
        setIsLoading(true); 
        loadEstad(estadId).then(() => {
            setIsLoading(false);
        });
    }, [dispatch, loadEstad]);

    console.log(estadId);
    console.log(goles);

    return (
        <ScrollView>
            <Image style={styles.image} source={{ uri: selectedPlayer.imagen }} />
            <View style={styles.dataContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.description}>Numero: <Text style={styles.subtitle}>{selectedPlayer.numero}</Text></Text>
                <Text style={styles.description}>Nombre Completo: <Text style={styles.subtitle}>{selectedPlayer.nombre_completo}</Text></Text>
                <Text style={styles.description}>Posicion: <Text style={styles.subtitle}>{selectedPlayer.posicion}</Text> </Text>
                <Text style={styles.description}>Edad: <Text style={styles.subtitle}>{selectedPlayer.edad}</Text></Text>
                <Text style={styles.description}>Nacionalidad: <Text style={styles.subtitle}>{selectedPlayer.nacionalidad}</Text></Text>
            </View>
        </ScrollView>
    );
};

export const screenOptions = navData => {
    return {
        headerTitle: navData.route.params.nombre,
    }
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    image: {
        width: '100%',
        height: 300,
    },
    subtitle: {
        fontSize: 16,
        textAlign: 'justify',
        marginVertical: 20,
        fontWeight:'normal',
    },
    description: {
        fontSize: 16,
        textAlign: 'center',
        marginVertical: 20,
        fontWeight: 'bold',

    },
    dataContainer:{
        width: '80%',
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginHorizontal: 40,
    },
    actions: {
        marginVertical: 10,
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
});

export default ProductDetailScreen;
```

However when I go to watch the Terminal I see that when I do the console.log(goles) which receives the slice of the Reducer I get Undefined.

I'm not sure what am I doing Wrong, any ideas?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import { SET_JUGADORES, SET_ESTADISTICA } from "../actions/jugadores";

const initialState = {
    availablePlayers: [],
    estadistica: [],
    playerGoals: [],
    playerCards: [],
    playerGames: [],
}

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_JUGADORES:
            return {
                ...state,
                availablePlayers: action.players,
            };
        case SET_ESTADISTICA:
            return{
                ...state,
                estadistica: state.estadistica,
                // playerGoals: action.goles,
                // playerCards: action.tarjetas,
                // playerGames: action.juegos
            };
    }
    return state;
};
```

Comment: Hi Jibbin, Thank you for the response, I tried but now I see an Empty Array, I'm not sure if it is something to do with the way my Action is requesting the data, I'm actually doubting the fetch request but I don't know if this is right: 
{
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: new Headers({
                        'x-rapidapi-key': '//API KEY goes here',
                        'x-rapidapi-host': 'api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com',
                        'useQueryString': 'true'
                    })
                }